# How to make JMH run in less time

Tags: jmh

We have a lot of JMH tests and when running the tests (using [gradle JMH plugin](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin)) they are taking a *long* time. All of our tests are single-threaded.

Can anyone advise how to best parallelise the execution of JMH tests? Our build box has plenty of CPU available.

Output from JMH gradle plugin as we have currently configured it (all defaults)

```
# JMH 1.12 ...
# VM options: <none>
# Warmup: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Measurement: 20 iterations, 1 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance tests are not supposed to be run in parallel for stability/reproducibility reasons. JMH would actually complain if you try to run several instances of JMH on the same system.

What you can do is to trim down the execution time *if that is proven not to violate test stability*. E.g. if you know that after 5 seconds warmup time the workloads stabilize at some score, you can do 5x1s warmup iterations. Ditto for measurement: if you know that less measurement iterations does not affect the errors you get, can trim that down too. The same with the number of forks.

JMH provides both annotations to override the default running mode (see e.g. [JMHSample20_Annotations](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/e96cad1fc480/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_20_Annotations.java), and the command line options too (run with `-h` to get the list).

Comment: Thanks Aleksey, appreciate your response. That all makes sense.

Comment: Consider adding a mode that skips further measurements if the error falls below a certain threshold (e.g. keep on iterating until the error falls below 1% of the score).